# cross domain ajax on a server hosted plugin without jquery or any helper library

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I have made a little JavaScript plugin that I can use like so in my web page reachable at `http://my_server/index.html`

```
<div id="foo"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://my_server/myPlugin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
myPlugin.init();
</script>
```

`myPlugin.js` makes ajax calls to `http://my_server/query?foo=bar` and adds more elements to the above page and works like a charm.

Now, I want to make this plugin usable by others. Imagine a user wants to implement it on a web page at `http://her_server/index.html` Except, now she gets an error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://my_server/query?foo=bar. 
Origin http://her_server/index.html is not allowed by 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

An additional wrinkle. For now I have the plugin hosted on `http://my_server/myPlugin.js` (yes, I want this to be a server side plugin) and the query server is the same `http://my_server/query?foo=bar`. However, in the future, they may be different servers. For example, the plugin at `http://my_plugin_server/myPlugin.js` and the query server at `http://my_query_server/query?foo=bar`.

Finally, all this is to be done without the help of jQuery or any other library. My ajax code is

```
"getData": function (q) {
    var uri = "http://my_server/query?foo=" + q;

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = handler;
    req.open("GET", uri, true);
    req.send();


    function handler(evt) {
        if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
            var json = eval('('+ req.responseText +')');
            .. do something with json ..
        }
    }
}
```